# SwiftUI ViewModel Update Function Not Working

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I recently created a new project (a quotebook project) that stores quotes and makes it so that you can like said quotes. However, when I was coding the function that adds likes and the one that removes it, it seemed to not work.

Here is my data model:

```
struct Quote: Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let content: String
    var likes: Int
    var color: String
    var liked: Bool
    
    init (id: String = UUID().uuidString, content: String, likes: Int, color: String, liked: Bool = false) {

        self.id = id
        self.content = content
        self.likes = like
        self.color = color
        self.liked = liked
    }
    
    func addLike() -> Quote {
        print("i got run")

        //never gets run

        return Quote(id: self.id, content: self.content, likes: (self.likes + 1), color: self.color, liked: !self.liked)
    }

    func removeLike() -> Quote {

        return Quote(id: id, content: content, likes: likes-1, color: color, liked: !liked)
    }   
}
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```
final class QuoteModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var quotes: [Quote] = []


    init() {
        self.createQuotes()
    }
    
    func createQuotes() -> Void{
        let tempQuotes: [Quote] = [
        Quote(content: "When life gives you lemons, you make lemonade!", likes: 47, color: "blue"),
        Quote(content: "I want nothing of the past nor the future; I want only the present", likes: 841, color: "blue"),
        Quote(content: "Power is not a means; it is an end", likes: 472, color: "blue"),
        Quote(content: "You cannot destroy truth by burning pages!", likes: 5492, color: "orange"),
        Quote(content: "We hold these truths to be self-evident; that all men are created equal", likes: 52, color: "yellow"),
        Quote(content: "Equal justice under law", likes: 462, color: "pink"),
        Quote(content: "No taxation without representation!", likes: 582, color: "purple"),
        Quote(content: "Why must we accept the past when we had no stakes in its creation?", likes: 32, color: "red"),
        ]

        quotes.append(contentsOf: tempQuotes 
    }    

    func addLike(quote: Quote) -> Void{
        print(quote.id)

        if let index = quotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == quote.id}) {
            //doesn't get to here 

            quotes[index] = quote.addLike()
        } else {
            print("not in list?") 
        }        
    }
   
    func removeLike(quote: Quote) -> Void {
        if let index = quotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == quote.id}) {
            //doesn't get to here 

            quotes[index] = quote.removeLike()
        } else {
            print("not in list?")
        }
    }     
}
```

The addLike and removeLike methods are both meant to run when a button is pressed.  I tried fixing it by checking all of the IDs in the list and seeing if they matched (they did). I think that this line is bugging: `if let index = quotes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == quote.id})` but I am not exactly sure why. It's hard for me to figure out as well because I'm not really sure how this line works.

If anyone sees any errors, please let me know. They may be really simple errors, as I am new to SwiftUI.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you add View's code as well? Need to check the `addLike` invocation.

Comment: Unrelated but in the addLike function you do `…, liked: !self.liked)` which must be wrong since a quote with 2 likes would then have liked == false. Personally I would make `liked` a computed property instead

Comment: struct Quote should works with self, and yo need to change self inside  addLike(), removeLine() methods